# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un POJO y un Bean en Java?

Tags: java, poo, object

He visto mucha similitud entre estos dos conceptos. Los dos tienen atributos protegidos y clases simples. Pero desearía saber cuál es su diferencia

Comment: Hola mira creo que esto puede ayudar a tu pregunta y como diferenciarlos :) http://carlospesquera.com/que-es-un-pojo-ejb-y-un-bean/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### POJO

POJO significa Plain Old Java Object. Se trata de un objeto Java común, no vinculado por ninguna restricción especial que no sea forzada por la especificación de lenguaje Java y que no requiera ninguna ruta de clase. POJOs se utilizan para aumentar la legibilidad y la reutilización de un programa. POJOs han ganado la mayoría de la aceptación porque son fáciles de escribir y de entender. Se introdujeron en EJB 3.0 por microsistemas Sun.

Un POJO no debe contener lo siguiente:

- Extender clases preespecificadas, Ej: `public class GFG extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {...}` no es una clase POJO.
- Implementar interfaces preespecificadas, Ej: `public class Bar implements javax.ejb.EntityBean {...}` no es una clase POJO.
- Anotaciones preespecificadas, Ej: `@javax.persistence.Entity public class Baz {...}` no es una clase POJO.

POJOs básicamente define una entidad. Si en tu programa deseas una clase de empleado, entonces puedes crear un POJO de la siguiente manera:

```
// Employee POJO clase que representa una entidad empleado
public class Employee
{
    // campo por defecto
    String name;

    // campo público
    public String id;

    // salario privado
    private double salary;

    //constructor para inicializar los campos
    public Employee(String name, String id, 
                             double salary)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    // getters
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public Double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }
}
```

El ejemplo anterior es un ejemplo bien definido de la clase POJO. Como puede ver, no hay restricción sobre el acceso-modificador de los campos. Pueden ser privados, predeterminados, protegidos o públicos. Tampoco es necesario incluir ningún constructor en él.

POJO es un objeto que encapsula la lógica de negocio (Business Logic). La siguiente imagen muestra un ejemplo práctico de la clase POJO. Los controladores interactúan con su lógica de negocio, que a su vez interactúan con POJO para acceder a la base de datos. En este ejemplo, una entidad de base de datos está representada por POJO. Este POJO tiene los mismos miembros que la entidad de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

#### BEANS

Los Beans son tipos especiales de POJOS. Hay algunas restricciones en POJO para que puedan ser Beans.

1. Todos los JavaBeans son POJO pero no todos los POJOs son JavaBeans.
2. Serializables, es decir, deben implementar la interfaz Serializable. Aún algunos POJOs que no implementan interfaz Serializable se llaman POJOs porque Serializable es una interfaz de marcadores y por lo tanto no de mucha carga.
3. Los campos deben ser privados. Esto es para proporcionar el control completo en los campos.
4. Los campos deben tener getters o setters o ambos.
5. Un constructor no-arg puede existir en un bean.
6. Se accede a los campos sólo por constructor o getter o setters.

Los Getters y Setters tienen algunos nombres especiales dependiendo del nombre del campo. Por ejemplo, si el nombre de campo es someProperty entonces su getter preferiblemente será:

```
public void getSomeProperty()
{
   return someProperty;
}
```

y el setter se llamará:

```
public void setSomePRoperty(someProperty)
{
   this.someProperty=someProperty;
}
```

La visibilidad de getters y setters en general es pública. Getters y setters proporcionan la restricción completa en los campos.

Si establece la visibilidad de la edad en público, entonces cualquier objeto puede usarla. Supongamos que desea que la edad no puede ser 0. En ese caso, no puede tener control. Cualquier objeto puede establecerla a 0. Pero utilizando el método setter, se tiene control. Usted puede tener una condición en su método de setter. Del mismo modo, para el método getter, si desea que si su edad es 0, entonces debería devolver null, puede lograr esto mediante el método getter como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
// Java program to illustrate JavaBeans
class Bean
{
    // private field property
    private Integer property;
    Bean()
    {
        // No-arg constructor
    }

    // setter method for property
    public void setProperty(Integer property)
    {
        if (property == 0)
        {
            // if property is 0 return
            return;
        }
        this.property=property;
    }

    // getter method for property
    public int getProperty()
    {
        if (property == 0)
        {
            // if property is 0 return null
            return null;
        }
        return property;
    }
}

// Class to test above bean
public class GFG
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Bean bean = new Bean();

        bean.setProperty(0);
        System.out.println("After setting to 0: " +
                                 bean.getProperty());

        bean.setProperty(5);
        System.out.println("After setting to valid" +
                      " value: " + bean.getProperty());
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
After setting to 0: null
After setting to valid value: 5
```

---

#### CONCLUSIÓN

Las clases POJO y Beans se utilizan para definir objetos Java para aumentar su legibilidad y reutilización. POJOs no tienen otras restricciones mientras que los Beans son POJOs especiales con algunas restricciones.

---

Fuente: [POJO vs Java Beans](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pojo-vs-java-beans/) (ver al final una interesante tabla comparativa).

Answer (score 7):

La únicas diferencias notables es que
un Java Bean puede ser [serializado](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) (aunque no se encuentra en la especificación) y un POJO únicamente puede heredar de un Object.

**[POJO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)**:

> son las iniciales de “Plain Old Java Object”, un POJO es una
>   instancia de una clase que no extiende ni implementa nada en especial.
>   Para los programadores Java sirve para enfatizar el uso de clases
>   simples y que no dependen de un framework en especial. Este concepto
>   surge en oposición al modelo planteado por los estándares EJB
>   anteriores al 3.0, en los que los Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) debían
>   implementar interfaces especiales.

**[Bean (JavaBean)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean)**:

> es una clase simple en Java que cumple con ciertas
>   normas con los nombres de sus propiedades y métodos.
>
> Un JavaBean debe tener un constructor sin argumentos, tiene declarados
>   todos sus atributos como privados y para cada uno de ellos un método
>   setter y getter, añadiéndole la palabra “set” o “get” al nombre del
>   atributo y deben ser serializables. Mediante estos JavaBeans,
>   desarrollamos nuestro modelo de objetos (o modelo de dominio) para la
>   aplicación.

Ejemplo:

```
public class MiBean implements java.io.Serializable {

   private int edad;
   private String nombre;

   //Constructor 
   public MiBean () {

   }

   public int getEdad() {
     return edad;
   }

   public void setEdad(int edad) {
     this.edad = edad;
   }

   public String getNombre() {
     return nombre;
   }

   public void setNombre(String nombre) {
     this.nombre = nombre;
   }

}
```

Te sugiero revises este documento para mayor información: ["Diferencia Java Bean vs POJO"](http://e-fayala.blogspot.mx/2009/07/diferencia-entre-pojo-y-bean.html?m=1)
y la especificación [JavaBeans](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/spec-136004.html).

Definición [POJO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) (Wikipedia):

Definición [JavaBean](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean) (Wikipedia):

Comment: En ninguna parte de la especificación JavaBean indica que debe ser serializable.

Comment: Gracias Elena system

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza se entiende que es sólo un ejemplo :)

Comment: @Hector un mal ejemplo...

Answer (score 0):

Un bean en Java se define en la [especificación JavaBeans](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf):

> “A Java Bean is a reusable software component that can be manipulated visually in a builder tool.”

Traducido a español:

> "Un Bean Java es un componente reusable de software que puede ser manipulado visualmente por una herramienta de desarrollo."

Se definen más elementos para un bean como la nomenclatura de atributos y métodos, los métodos de acceso a los atributos, el soporte a eventos, entre otros.

POJO hace referencia a Plain Old Java Object. Esto se refiere a una clase con atributos privados o protegidos y que solo provee métodos getter y setter protegidos o públicos para acceder a los atributos. Similar a cuando defines una entidad. Un POJO es un JavaBean mientras que un JavaBean no necesariamente es un POJO.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración